# How do I know coordinates of both ends of cylinder

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to show text top of cylinder

How do I know coordinates of both ends of cylinder?

Comment: You could get the height and the add and subtract half of this amount to the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standart Unity cylinder is 2 units talls (when local scale is 1). So top end is y+1 and the bottom is y-1.

C# code to get top and bottom points:

`Vector3 MyCylinderTopSpot = Cylinder.transform.position + (new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * Cylinder.transform.localScale.y); //Cylinder type is GameObject`

`Vector3 MyCylinderBottomSpot = Cylinder.transform.position + (new Vector3(0, -1, 0) * Cylinder.transform.localScale.y);`